# Does Guava provide a method to unescape a String?

Tags: java, guava

I need to escape special characters in a `String`.

Guava provides the [`Escaper`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/escape/Escaper.html) class, which does exactly this:

```
Escaper escaper = Escapers.builder()
        .addEscape('[', "\\[")
        .addEscape(']', "\\]")
        .build();

String escapedStr = escaper.escape("This is a [test]");

System.out.println(escapedStr);
// -> prints "This is a \[test\]"
```

Now that I have an escaped `String`, I need to unescape it and I can't find anything in Guava to do this.

I was expecting `Escaper` to have a `unescape()` method, but it isn't the case.

**Edit :** I'm aware that unescaping can be tricky, even impossible in some non-sense cases.

For example, this `Escaper` usage can lead to ambiguities :

```
Escaper escaper = Escapers.builder()
        .addEscape('@', " at ")
        .addEscape('.', " dot ")
        .build();
```

Unless the escaped data contains only email addresses and nothing more, you can't safely get your data back by unescaping it.

A good example of a safe usage of the `Escaper` is HTML entities :

```
Escaper escaper = Escapers.builder()
        .addEscape('&', "&amp;")
        .addEscape('<', "&lt;")
        .addEscape('>', "&gt;")
        .build();
```

Here, you can safely escape any text, incorporate it in a HTML page and *unescape* it at any time to display it, because you covered every possible ambiguities.

In conclusion, I don't see why unescaping is so controversial. I think it is the developper's responsability to use this class properly, knowing his data and avoiding ambiguities.
Escaping, by definition, means you will eventually need to unescape. Otherwise, it's obfuscation or some other concept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not. And apparently, this is intentional. Quoting from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/guava-discuss/zqkjYlz57bY) where Chris Povirk answered:

> The use case for unescaping is less clear to me.  It's generally not
>   possible to even identify the escaped source text without a parser
>   that understands the language.  For example, if I have the following
>   input:
>
> ```
> String s = "foo\n\"bar\"\n\\";
> ```
>
> Then my parser has to already understand `\n`, `\"`, and `\\` in order to
>   identify that...
>
> ```
> foo\n\"bar\"\n\\
> ```
>
> ...is the text to be "unescaped."  In other words, it has to do the
>   unescaping already.  The situation is similar with HTML and other
>   formats:  We don't need an unescaper so much as we need a parser.

So it looks like you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: I don't get it. In my case, the text to be *unescaped* is well known: it's in `escapedStr`. I don't need to parse the Java code, I only need to remove escape sequences in a simple String.

Comment: @EricCitaire Escaping is mostly used for HTML or XML content. I guess the Guava devs didn't see the added value of just having a unescaper for simple Strings.

Comment: Can you give us some more background? What do you do with the string between when you escape it and when you unescape it? What do you do with it after you unescape it?

Comment: @ChrisPovirk You might want to comment on the question so that the OP gets notified of it.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk I need to serialize a list of values by joining them with separators (`-`, `_`, etc.). If a value contains the given separator, I need to replace it with a *safe* character, so I can split them on deserialization and replace the *safe* character by the original litteral. I'm currently using a simple `Map` and iterate over it, replacing the key (separator) by the value (*safe* character). On deserialization, I just revert the `Map` and do it again. I found the `Escaper` class and I thought it would fit my needs and save me this boilerplate code.

Comment: Put differently, the answer is that the "unecape" method cannot be defined from the "espace" method. Consider this espaper `\`` → `/` and `_` → `/`. How would you unescape `/foo`?

Comment: @EricCitaire Thanks. My concern is usually this: What if you want to store `abc`, `def,ghi`? What a lot of people do is convert it to `abc,def\,ghi`. To get the original back, you can't just split on `,` and then unescape; you need a more sophisticated parser. It sounds like, in your case, you might be avoiding this by replacing `,` with something that doesn't mention `,`, say: `abc,def\{comma}ghi`. You can then handle backslash the same way, converting `c:\` to `c:\{backslash}`. Now you're in a position to split on comma and unescape. Is that right?

Comment: @rds Provided that the developper configured the `Escaper` properly (ie he didn't use the same escape sequence for a given character), the `unescape` method can be defined from the `escape` method.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk That's not exactly the strategy we used because of some boring requirements, but that's not my point. I was just curious about the lack of an `unescape` method, which, in my case, makes the `Escaper` useless. I just would like to understand why this was not implemented.

Comment: @EricCitaire Maybe someone else can give a better explanation than the one quoted above, "because most use cases require a full parser": When you're escaping text, it's usually to put it in some other program or document. To interpret that output, you need to understand the full language, not just its escaping rules. There are exceptions, and your use case might be one. If you're interested in discussing that, we can try to work it out from your requirements. We might also find a way to unescape with string substitution or regex or something.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk see my edit. I'm not covering my particular use case. In fact, I don't really want to. It's more a general thinking about this controversal unescaping thing that I want to discuss. :)

Comment: @EricCitaire OK, I've probably been coming at this the wrong way. If you're asking why `Escaper` doesn't have an `unescape` method, then the answer is that many users don't need unescaping, so we don't want to force it on all `Escaper` implementations. If you're asking why `Escapers.Builder` does not have a `buildUnescaper()` method that returns a separate `Unescaper` type (or, if we decide we don't want a new type, an `Escaper` that unescapes), then the answer is that no one's ever proposed anything that concrete, so we haven't been able to evaluate the costs and benefits.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk IMHO, the `Escaper` should be symetrical. If the *unescape* counterpart is implemented, I think it should be a method of the `Escaper` class, which contains all the useful informations to do it. Of course, it might not worth the effort if nobody needs it. As you mentioned, most of the time the unescaping is done by *something else*, like a browser for example. Let me know if you decide to introduce this in Guava, I'd be glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

If you just need to unescape HTML entities, Unicode characters and control characters like `\n` or `\t` you can simply use the [StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) class from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang).

Answer (score 0):

In case if anybody will ever need a single char unescaper, here's one dead simple implementation below:

```
@Nonnull
public String unescape(@Nonnull String text) {
    CharacterIterator i = new StringCharacterIterator(text);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.length());
    for (char c = i.first(); c != DONE; c = i.next()) {
        if (c == escaped) {
            result.append(i.next());
        } else {
            result.append(c);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Where is `escaped` defined?