# Text encoding that produces legible encodings suitable as Javascript identifiers?

Tags: javascript, encoding, base64, ascii, urlencode

I'm working on a tool that reads arbitrary data files and creates a table out of its data which I then store in a database. I'd like to preserve the column headers. The column headers are already ASCII text (or maybe latin1), but they have characters that aren't valid variable names (e.g., spaces, %), so I need to encode them somehow. I'm looking for an encoding for the column titles that has these properties:

1. **Legible**: it would be nice if the encoded text looked as similar as possible to the unencoded text (i.e., for debugging).
2. **Legal identifier**: I'd like the encoded text to be a valid JavaScript identifier ([ECMA-262 Section 7.6](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6)).
3. **Invertible**: I'd like to be able to get the exact original text back from the encoded text.

I can think of approaches that work for 2 of the 3 cases, but I don't know how to get all 3. E.g., `url encoding` doesn't produce legal identifier names, I think I could transform `base64` to be legal, but it isn't legible, what I've got currently  just does some substitutions so it's not invertible.

Efficiency isn't a concern, so if necessary, I could store the encoded and unencoded texts together. The best option I can think of is to use `url encoding` and then swap percents for `$`. I thought there would be better options than this though, but I can't find anything. Is there anything better?

Comment: property names != variable names; which do you need?

Comment: edited for clarification, but I'm wondering if there are encodings/algorithms that could be more general than the rules of a given context

Answer (score 0):

This pair of methods relying on Guava's `PercentEscaper` seems to meet my requirements. Guava [doesn't provide an unescaper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34091458/319034), but given my simple needs here, I can just use a simple URLDecoder.

```
private static PercentEscaper escaper = new PercentEscaper('',false)

static String getIdentifier(String str) {
    //minimal safe characters, but leaves letters alone, so it's somewhat legible
    String escaped = escaper.escape(str);

    //javascript identifiers can't start with a digit, and the escaper doesn't know the first
    //character has different rules. so prepend a "%3" to encode the digit
    if(Character.isDigit(escaped.charAt(0))){
        escaped = "%3"+escaped
    }

    //a percent isn't a valid in a javascript identifier, so we'll use _ as our special character
    escaped = escaped.replace('%','_');

    return escaped;
}

static String invertIdentifier(String str){
    String unescaped = str.replace('_','%');
    unescaped = URLDecoder.decode(unescaped, "UTF-8");
    return unescaped;
}
```

Comment: You might consider using $ as your escape character sine it is valid anywhere in an identifer

Comment: That's what I tried initially... but my server side code is groovy and the `$` means string interpolation so hard-coded keys were a little harder to work with. As far as Javascript is concerned, a `_` and a `$` are equivalent.